# Special charcters encoding in html string

Tags: html, powershell, encoding, smtp

I am using below code to send mails using a PowerShell script:

```
$HTMLmessage = "test beigefügt Zusätzlich verfügbar.   äöüß"

Send-MailMessage -From $fromemail -To $users -Subject "Test through ps" -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) -BodyAsHTML -Body $HTMLmessage -Priority Normal -SmtpServer $server ;
```

But it's giving me output in email like:

> test beigefÃ¼gt ZusÃ¤tzlich verfÃ¼gbar. Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃŸ

Do you hav any idea how to fix that?

EDIT

```
$HTMLmessage = $HTMLmessage | ConvertTo-Html
$HTMLmessage = "test beigefügt Zusätzlich verfügbar.   äöüß"
Send-MailMessage -From $fromemail -To $users -Subject "Test through ps" -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) -BodyAsHTML -Body $HTMLmessage -Priority Normal -SmtpServer $server ;
```

But its giving me same o/p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the concept here.

The issues not in *powershell* nor in *smtp*.  From the looks of your code it appears to be an **HTML** encoding issue.  The issue is that the receiving side of your message does not understand that you are using different encoding in your HTML message.

Try adding a encoding to your content.

For `ISO-8859-1`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```

For `UTF-8`:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

To work with your script:

```
$HTMLMessage = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'
$HTMLMessage += 'test beigefügt Zusätzlich verfügbar.   äöüß'
```

Only after than send the email via `send-mailmessage`.

**Edit1 && 2**

Ah, you did not convert the message body to html before.  You are probably right that the `-Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)` should be enough.
Apparently, I was too quick.  Lets do it properly.

```
$HTMLMessage = '<html>'
$HTMLMessage += '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'
$HTMLMessage += '<body>test beigefügt Zusätzlich verfügbar. äöüß</body>'
$HTMLMessage += '</html>'

send-mailmessage -from $fromemail -to $users -subject "Test through ps" -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) -BodyAsHTML -body $HTMLmessage -priority Normal -smtpServer $server
```

From our discussion it appears you had wrong file encoding.  If you have it in plain *UTF8 without signature*.  The source file should be in *UTF-8 with signature* it also works with *UTF16BE with signature*.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> has been already applied through  -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) .No change found after adding $HTMLMessage = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'

Comment: @Amol Ok, I'm pretty sure it is with the html body - for you to try.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much for ur support. I am new to this power shell coding .pls check my edit code.I am still facing same issue.

Comment: @Amol could you please show the html source for your email message?

Comment: HTML scource : <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">test beigefÃ¼gt ZusÃ¤tzlich verfÃ¼gbar.   Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃŸ

Comment: @Amol I mean the received message.  That is all?

Comment: Yes. its all email's view source extract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167157/discussion-between-amol-and-tukan).